# How to deliver activity result to fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am trying to make deliver result from activity to fragment which is on that activity.

There are 4 fragment and 5 buttons. 4 buttons are for change the fragment, the remain thing is for voice recognition button.
What I want to do is put the result on fragment's cost, explanation field from voice recognition when voice input is done.

My code is crashed right after voice recognition is done. I want to know why it is not working and what should I do to get it works.

This is Activity code

```
public class InputActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
private final int GOOGLE_STT = 1000;
private ArrayList<String> mResult;                                  //음성인식 결과 저장할 list
String mResultTextView01;
String mResultTextView02;

final String TAG = "InputActivity";
int mCurrentFragmentIndex;
public final static int FRAGMENT_ONE = 0;
public final static int FRAGMENT_TWO = 1;
public final static int FRAGMENT_THREE = 2;
public final static int FRAGMENT_FOUR = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);

    Button bt_oneFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_oneFragment);
    Button bt_twoFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_twoFragment);
    Button bt_threeFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_threeFragment);
    Button bt_fourFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_fourFragment);
    bt_oneFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt_twoFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt_threeFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt_fourFragment.setOnClickListener(this);


    mCurrentFragmentIndex = FRAGMENT_ONE;
    fragmentReplace(mCurrentFragmentIndex);


}

public void fragmentReplace(int reqNewFragmentIndex) {

    Fragment newFragment = null;
    newFragment = getFragment(reqNewFragmentIndex);

    // replace fragment
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.display_fragment, newFragment);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();

}

private Fragment getFragment(int idx) {
    Fragment newFragment = null;

    switch (idx) {
    case FRAGMENT_ONE:
        newFragment = new ExpenseCashFragment();
        break;
    case FRAGMENT_TWO:
        newFragment = new ExpenseAccountFragment();
        break;
    case FRAGMENT_THREE:
        newFragment = new EarningCashFragment();
        break;
    case FRAGMENT_FOUR:
        newFragment = new EarningAccountFragment();
        break;

    default:
        Log.d(TAG, "Unhandle case");
        break;
    }

    return newFragment;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bt_oneFragment:
        mCurrentFragmentIndex = FRAGMENT_ONE;
        fragmentReplace(mCurrentFragmentIndex);
        break;
    case R.id.bt_twoFragment:
        mCurrentFragmentIndex = FRAGMENT_TWO;
        fragmentReplace(mCurrentFragmentIndex);
        break;
    case R.id.bt_threeFragment:
        mCurrentFragmentIndex = FRAGMENT_THREE;
        fragmentReplace(mCurrentFragmentIndex);
        break;
    case R.id.bt_fourFragment:
        mCurrentFragmentIndex = FRAGMENT_FOUR;
        fragmentReplace(mCurrentFragmentIndex);
        break;
    default:

    }

}
public void on_bt_voice(View v){

    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());   
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ko-KR");       
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "말을 하세요.");                       
    InputActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i, GOOGLE_STT);
}


@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
     if( resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GOOGLE_STT)
        {
         showResult(requestCode, data);
        }
        else{
            String msg = null;

            switch(resultCode){
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                    msg = "오디오 입력 중 오류가 발생했습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                    msg = "단말에서 오류가 발생했습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                    msg = "권한이 없습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                    msg = "네트워크 오류가 발생했습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                    msg = "일치하는 항목이 없습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                    msg = "음성인식 서비스가 과부하 되었습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                    msg = "서버에서 오류가 발생했습니다.";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                    msg = "입력이 없습니다.";
                    break;
            }

            if(msg != null) 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void showResult(int requestCode, Intent data){
        String key = "";
        if(requestCode == GOOGLE_STT)                   //구글음성인식이면
            key = RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS;   //키값 설정

        mResult = data.getStringArrayListExtra(key);        //인식된 데이터 list 받아옴.
        String[] result = new String[mResult.size()];           //배열생성.
        mResult.toArray(result);//  list 배열로 변환
        String i = result[0];
        String[] count = i.split(" ");
        mResultTextView01 = count[0];
        mResultTextView02 = count[1];
        if(requestCode == GOOGLE_STT){
            Log.d(TAG, "fjfj");
             ResultTofragment(mResultTextView01, mResultTextView02);
        }
    }

    ///음성인식 결과값 전달 인텐트

public void ResultTofragment(String a, String b){
    Log.d(TAG, "fj");
    switch(mCurrentFragmentIndex)
    {
    case FRAGMENT_ONE:
         Intent intent1 = new Intent(InputActivity.this, ExpenseCashFragment.class);
            intent1.putExtra("t1", a);
            intent1.putExtra("t2", b);
            InputActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);
         break;
    case FRAGMENT_TWO:
         Intent intent2 = new Intent(InputActivity.this, ExpenseAccountFragment.class);
            intent2.putExtra("t1", a);
            intent2.putExtra("t2", b);
            InputActivity.this.startActivity(intent2);
         break;
    case FRAGMENT_THREE:
         Intent intent3 = new Intent(InputActivity.this, EarningCashFragment.class);
            intent3.putExtra("t1", a);
            intent3.putExtra("t2", b);
            InputActivity.this.startActivity(intent3);
         break;
    case FRAGMENT_FOUR:
         Intent intent4 = new Intent(InputActivity.this, EarningAccountFragment.class);
            intent4.putExtra("t1", a);
            intent4.putExtra("t2", b);
            InputActivity.this.startActivity(intent4);
         break;
    } 
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.input, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.item1:
        HomeItem();
        break;

    default:
    }
    return true;
}

private void HomeItem() 
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Go to Home")
    .setMessage("Want to go to Home?")
    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(InputActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            InputActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).show();

}
}
```

And this is one of my fragments code

```
public class ExpenseCashFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener 
{

DatePicker datepicker;
Spinner spinner;
Button button;
EditText cost, explanation;
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
String st; // Just for transferring the category data

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expensecashfragment, container, false);

    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.expenseCategory, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    datepicker = (DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);

    cost = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_cost);
    explanation = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_explanation);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.enterButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    //If you want to use this in Activity in the Fragment use getActivity() instead

   getVoiceResult();

    openDB();
    return view;
}
public void getVoiceResult(){
    //
    Intent intent1 = getActivity().getIntent();
    String voiceResult01 = intent1.getStringExtra("t1");
    String voiceResult02 = intent1.getStringExtra("t2");
    //
    cost.setText(""+voiceResult01);
    explanation.setText(""+voiceResult02);
    Log.d(getTag(), "ggggs");
    //
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void closeDB() 
{
    dbAdapter.close();
}


private void openDB() {
    dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    dbAdapter.openW();

}

public void enterData()
{
    String date = setDate();

    if(cost.getText().toString() == null)
        return;

    int cost_value = Integer.parseInt(cost.getText().toString());
    String explanation_value = explanation.getText().toString();
    //Message.message(getActivity(), date + " " + st + " " + cost_value + " " + explanation_value );
    //category string is in the st

    CashExpenseTable ce = new CashExpenseTable(date, st, cost_value, explanation_value);
    long id = dbAdapter.addCashExpense(ce);

    if(id > 0)
    {
        Message.message(getActivity(), "Successfully inserted a row " + id);
    }
    else
    {
        Message.message(getActivity(), "Unsuccessful");
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class));

}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// For the spinner

public void showDialog(View v)
{   
    }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    TextView myText = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You selected " + myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    st = (String) myText.getText();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// For the datePicker
public String setDate()
{
    int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datepicker.getMonth() + 1;
    int year = datepicker.getYear();

    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.enterButton:
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Input completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enterData();
        break;

    default:
    }
}


}
```

This is logcat

```
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.money/com.example.money.ExpenseCashFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.money.ExpenseCashFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4946)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.money.ExpenseCashFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
11-26 04:50:17.075: E/AndroidRuntime(11263):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ResultTofragment function you are using the class object of your four fragments, and trying to start the fragments as if they were activities. That is why you get the ClassCastException.

I believe your intent is to show the selected fragment, and pass the Intent extras you are adding in that function as arguments to the fragment. There are a number of ways to achieve this. One way is to add a Bundle parameter to your fragmentReplace function, and then pass it to the fragment using setArguments:

```
public void ResultTofragment(String a, String b){
    Log.d(TAG, "fj");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence("t1", a);
    args.putCharSequence("t2", b);
    fragmentReplace(mCurrentFragmentIndex, args);
}

public void fragmentReplace(int reqNewFragmentIndex, Bundle args) {
    Fragment newFragment = null;
    newFragment = getFragment(reqNewFragmentIndex);

    if (args != null) {
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
    }

    // replace fragment
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.display_fragment, newFragment);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Note that for the other places you call fragmentReplace, when you don't have arguments yet, you can pass null. Finally, in your fragments, you would get the arguments from the Bundle, instead of the activity's intent extras:

```
public void getVoiceResult(){
    //
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    CharSequence voiceResult01 = args.getCharSequence("t1");
    CharSequence voiceResult02 = args.getCharSequence("t2");
    //
    cost.setText(""+voiceResult01);
    explanation.setText(""+voiceResult02);
    Log.d(getTag(), "ggggs");
    //
}
```